# Mean value theorem for essentially bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the problem with the following:

Let $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ is the mean value theorem in the following form:

> Let $0 \leq a < b < \infty$, then
>
> $\int_{a}^{b} |f| \ d\mu = m(b-a)$, for some $m \leq \mathrm{ess} \sup |f|$.

valid for $f$?

We can see that
$$\int_{a}^b |f| \ d\mu \leq \mathrm{ess} \sup |f|(b-a)$$

thus $f \in L^1([a,b])$. Then $\mathrm{ess} \inf |f| = - \mathrm{ess} \sup |f|$, so

$$\mathrm{ess} \inf |f|(b-a) \leq \int_{a}^b |f| \ d\mu.$$ Thus the intermidiate value theorem applied to $|f|$ shows that there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $|f(x)| \in [\mathrm{ess} \inf |f|,\mathrm{ess} \sup|f| ]$ and
$$ \int_{a}^b |f| \ d\mu = |f(x)| (b-a) .$$
Is it correct?

How about the following:

> Let $0 \leq a < b < \infty$,  does it exist a complex number $m$ such that
>
> $\int_{a}^{b} f \ d\mu = m(b-a)$, for some $|m| \leq \mathrm{ess} \sup |f|$.

I think for that we could use that $f= \mathrm{Re}f + i \mathrm{Im} f$ and then apply thesis from the first question (if it is true).
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts are correct, others are not. You observed correctly that $\def\esssup{\mathop{\mathrm{ess\,sup}}}\def\essinf{\mathop{\mathrm{ess\,inf}}}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
$$ 
 \essinf \abs f \cdot (b-a) \le \int_a^b \abs f \, dx \le \esssup \abs f \cdot (b-a) \tag 1
$$
But in in gerenal doesn't that $\essinf \abs f = -\esssup \abs f$, note for example, that $f \ge 0$. This inequality follows from
$$ \essinf \abs f \le \abs{f(x)} \le \esssup\abs f, \quad \text{a. e. $x \in [a,b]$} $$
Moreover note, that $\abs f$ will in general not be continuous, so you cannot just apply the MVT to it.

To prove you theorem, divide (1) by $b-a$ and obtain
$$ \essinf \abs f \le \frac 1{(b-a)}\int_a^b \abs f \, dx \le \esssup \abs f $$
Now let $m := (b-a)^{-1}\int_a^b \abs f \, dx$, then $m \in [\essinf \abs f, \esssup \abs f]$ and
$$ \int_a^b \abs f\, dx = m(b-a).$$

Comment: Yes, of course IVT works only for continuous functions. So the constant $m$ in the general case depends on $a$ and $b$ much more than in the continuous case where it is a value of $f$ at some point from the interval.